# Possible to Preload a UIView that contains a library of information?

Tags: uiview

Is is possible to have a UIView preloaded so that it will load faster when the user taps on button to load it? Currently I've got a library of informaiton that I'm attempting to load when the user taps a button, and for now it seems to be "ok" , but it makes the navigation to the page choppy, because of all the information in the library it's loading.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to split the setup of a View Controller from code that displays the view after a button is pushed. This will eliminate the lag when the button but the task to setup the view controller still need to be done sometime during execution (You can for example put it in the  ViewdidAppear method so it is executed while waiting for the button to be pushed.

Take this code for example:

```
  -(IBAction) button_pushed {
      /*setup */
        NewVC *vc = [[NewVC alloc] init];
       vc.var1 = var1;
        vc.var2 = x;
        [vc setup];

      /*display */
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

 return;
}
```

You can split the code that setup the view from the code that displays the view 
 into :

```
     @synthesize vc;
```

…..

```
  - (NewVC) setup {
     //setup
       NewVC *vc1 = [[NewVC alloc] init];
       vc.var1 = var1;
       vc.var2 = x;
       [vc setup];
       return(vc1);
```

}

```
-(void) ViewDidAppear {
   if (setupready) { 
           vc = [self setup];}
       return;
    }
```

-(IBAction) button_pushed:(ID) sender {

```
   //display
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

 return;
}
```